# Existing motion planner for double Ackermann kynematics?

Tags: ros, moveit, path, planner, ompl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a robot with double ackermann kynematics/steering, this means that the unlike in a conventional car, you can also steer the rear wheels and make use of crab like steering. Is there any open source path planner for these kind of robots? Can  for example OMPL be used for this?

Cheers,

Oier

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/147021/existing-motion-planner-for-double-ackermann-kynematics?/) by [Oier](https://answers.ros.org/users/3642/oier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 145 on 2014-04-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-04-01**:
Are you looking for a planner for the ROS navigation stack, or just a generic motion planning library?

**Comment by [Oier](https://answers.ros.org/users/3642/oier/) on 2014-04-07**:
@ahendrix I am looking just for a generic motion planning library, because the ROS navigation stack and MoveIt have too much overhead/features for my applications requirements. But the robot is built upon ROS and I use rviz for simulation. What motion planners can be used for double ackermann?

**Comment by [abraham](https://answers.ros.org/users/39945/abraham/) on 2019-02-27**:
can you please post the link to you urdf file am planning to do slam double Ackerman ,but  i can't able to fine any sample to start with .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I´d also recommend using the [sbpl_lattice_planner](http://wiki.ros.org/sbpl_lattice_planner). We selectively use it on our double Ackermann steering USAR robots in case our exploration planner generates a plan that cannot be followed by the vehicle (because it would need to turn in place). That approach works pretty well both in [simulation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cd2FGMBj8iw) and with [the real robot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PKI378kadp8).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Oier](https://answers.ros.org/users/3642/oier/) on 2014-04-08**:
thanks @Stefan Kohlbrecher! What made you choose sbpl_lattice_planner over a sampling based method like RRT with motion primitives?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-04-09**:
SBPL was the only motion primitive based approach that was proven and already available as a ROS package, so we tried it first, with success.

**Comment by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on 2016-03-22**:
@Stefan Kohlbrecher, can your give a little example how you created the mprim file with matlab? I dont get the introduction located at their homepage